Sql Server Azure Managed Instance with Encrypted Column. Key Value had new version created and now can't read column
We have several databases running on an Sql Managed Instance in azure. They have encrypted columns configured with the Keys stored in azure. The key versions were about to expire so our admin clicked the new version button and created a new version of the key. We can now not read the encrypted for some of the databases.
Looking in the sys.column_master_keys table of the databases that we can still read the key is pointing to the specific version that is no longer the current version. The databases that won't work are just pointing to the key not a specific version. We can alter the column in sys.column_master_keys to have it point to the specific version as ad hoc queries on system tables are not allowed. We can't remove the newly created version on KeyVault as that is not allowed.
Setting the newly created version the disabled doesn't seem to work either. We are waiting on azure support, but in the meantime we have customers down.
Any suggestions?
